# TypeError: export() got an unexpected keyword argument 'set_timezone'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a question, in my code i get an error: `TypeError: export() got an unexpected keyword argument 'set_timezone'`
And i really dont know how to fix it. I want to archive a channel in discord with using [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)
and the module [chat_exporter](https://pypi.org/project/chat-exporter/). But there is a TypeError within the `set timezone`.

Here is the code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(MANAGEMENT_ROLE_ID)
async def archive(channel, archive_channel):
        if channel and archive_channel:
            transcript = await chat_exporter.export(channel, set_timezone='UTC')
            transcript_file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(transcript.encode()), filename=f"{channel.name}.html")
            await archive_channel.send(file=transcript_file)
```

And that is the console log

```
Ignoring exception in command archive:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Discord\discord Bots\derzockereckenbot 2.0\main.py", line 134, in archive
    transcript = await chat_exporter.export(channel, set_timezone='UTC')
TypeError: export() got an unexpected keyword argument 'set_timezone'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: export() got an unexpected keyword argument 'set_timezone'
```

Can please anyone help me?

Comment: Which documentation includes `set_timezone` as a kwarg of `export`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'` means that you've passed a keyword to the function which isn't in the parameters of the function. In your case it's `set_timezone`.

If you look at the function definition, you can see there's no kwarg called `set_timezone`:

```py
async def export(
    channel: discord.TextChannel,
    limit: Optional[int] = None,
    tz_info="UTC",
    guild: Optional[discord.Guild] = None,
):
```

Instead it's `tz_info`. So, for your code:

```py
transcript = await chat_exporter.export(channel, tz_info="UTC")
```

For `UTC` you don't even need to pass a value for `tz_info`, because the default value is already `UTC`.

Comment: Ohhh, okay thank you so much, i should read the next time the Documentation bevore asking here.

Comment: I can't upvote it says

Comment: @Joniii11 but you can choose correct answer

Answer (score 0):

How i see from documentation:

> Optional Argument(s): limit: Integer value to set the limit (amount of
> messages) the chat exporter gathers when grabbing the history
> (default=unlimited). **tz_info: String value of a TZ Database name to
> set a custom timezone for the exported messages (default=UTC)**
> military_time: Boolean value to set a 24h format for times within your
> exported chat (default=False | 12h format) bot: commands.Bot object to
> gather members who are no longer in your guild.

example:

```
@bot.command()
async def save(ctx: commands.Context, limit: int, tz_info: str, military_time: bool):
    transcript = await chat_exporter.export(
        ctx.channel,
        limit=limit,
        tz_info=tz_info,
        military_time=military_time
        bot=bot,
    )
```

**So may be you should use `tz_info` instead of `set_timezone`?**

Comment: Ohhh, okay thank you so much, i should read the next time the Documentation bevore asking here.

Comment: @Joniii11 you posted hyperlink to package where contains link to github repo :)